# Netlify-cms existing collection items are not displayed even if github request returns item

Tags: gatsby, github-api, netlify-cms

I'm using netlify-cms `2.10.68`, netlify-cms-app `2.11.20` with Gatsby `2.26.1` to do a simple event listing site.

When I restart the server or redeploy, existing collection items are not displayed in the cms.

When checking the network traffic to github to retrieve the items it returns them fine.

Little bit lost as to where to look next?

Here's:

The Network response from github made by netlify-cms

```
{
  "sha": "3.....",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/organisation/repo/git/trees/3.......",
  "tree": [
    {
      "path": "test-webinar-1.md",
      "mode": "100644",
      "type": "blob",
      "sha": "a....",
      "size": 133,
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/organisation/repo/git/blobs/a...."
    }
  ],
  "truncated": false
}
```

my `./static/admin/config.yml`

```
backend:
  name: github
  repo: repo_name
  branch: production
media_folder: static/images/uploads
public_folder: images/uploads

collections:
  - name: 'webinar'
    label: 'Webinar'
    folder: '/data/events/webinar'
    nested:
      depth: 100
    slug: '{{slug}}'
    create: true
    filter: { field: 'Type', value: 'Webinar' }
    path: '{{title}}'
    fields:
      - { name: 'title', label: 'Event Name' }
      - label: 'Event Type'
        name: 'event_type'
        widget: 'select'
        multiple: false
        description: 'Event Type (Conference, Webinar, Workshop etc.)'
        options: ['Conference', 'Webinar', 'Workshop']
      - { name: 'date', label: 'Date', widget: 'datetime' }
      - label: 'Event Status'
        name: 'status'
        widget: 'select'
        multiple: false
        description: 'Page status'
        options: ['Draft', 'Hidden', 'Testing', 'Public', 'Private']
      - { name: 'body', label: 'Body', widget: 'markdown' }
```

My `./package.json`

```
{
  "name": "event-microsite",
  "description": "Did you want some events?",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "clean": "gatsby clean",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "fd": "gatsby clean && gatsby develop",
    "fpd": "gatsby clean && gatsby build && gatsby deploy",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,md}\" \"!{package.json, yarn.lock, .cache/*, public/*\"",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing\" && exit 1",
    "precommit": "yarn format"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@types/js-cookie": "^2.2.6",
    "codemirror": "^5.58.2",
    "gatsby": "^2.26.1",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.6.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-hubspot": "^1.3.4",
    "gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms": "4.1.40",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.5.0",
    "gatsby-source-hubspot-forms": "^2.2.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^2.10.0",
    "immutable": "3.7.6",
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "^3.1.0",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "netlify-cms": "^2.10.68",
    "netlify-cms-app": "2.11.20",
    "netlify-cms-lib-util": "^2.11.5",
    "netlify-cms-lib-widgets": "^1.6.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "redux": "^3.0.5",
    "seamless-immutable": "^7.1.4",
    "typescript": "^4.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.11.6",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.8.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.8.1",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-preset-gatsby": "^0.6.0",
    "core-js": "^3.7.0",
    "eslint": "^7.13.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.15.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "mouseflow": "^1.0.3",
    "prettier": "2.1.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.12.0",
    "sentry": "^0.1.2",
    "stylelint": "^13.8.0",
    "stylelint-config-airbnb": "^0.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-recommended": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.5.1"
  },
  "stylelint": {
    "extends": "stylelint-config-airbnb"
  },
  "prettier": {
    "arrowParens": "avoid",
    "semi": false,
    "printWidth": 100,
    "singleQuote": true
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "env": {
      "browser": true,
      "es2021": true,
      "es6": true,
      "jest": true,
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "airbnb-typescript/base",
      "eslint:recommended",
      "plugin:react/recommended",
      "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
      "prettier",
      "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
      "prettier/react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "prettier",
      "@typescript-eslint",
      "react"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaFeatures": {
        "jsx": true
      },
      "ecmaVersion": 12,
      "sourceType": "module",
      "project": "./tsconfig.json"
    },
    "root": true,
    "rules": {
      "prettier/prettier": [
        "error"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you `git pull`/`rebase` your local?

Comment: Yes, of course, my local repo reflects the content in production branch. It's unusual because media files can be accessed but not the content files.

Comment: Do you see a kind of empty card in your local CMS for your entries (in your collection)?

Comment: Nope,  no cards display blank or otherwise, it displays `No entries`.  Pursuing a custom cms.js file to see if I resolve there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the CMS Collection.

specifically these two lines

```
filter: { field: 'Type', value: 'Webinar' }
fields:
  - label: 'Event Type'
    name: 'event_type'
    widget: 'select'
    multiple: false
    description: 'Event Type (Conference, Webinar, Workshop etc.)'
    options: ['Conference', 'Webinar', 'Workshop']
```

The Field is wrongly referenced.